# httplib2 socket.sslerror: (-1, 'SSL exception')

Tags: python, ssl, jython

When trying to use httplib2 to do a HTTPS GET, I get the following error.

```
>>> import httplib2
>>> http = httplib2.Http(cache=None, timeout=30)
>>> response, content = http.request('https://www.example.com', 'GET')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/jython/2.5.2/Lib/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1436, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/app/jython/2.5.2/Lib/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1188, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/app/jython/2.5.2/Lib/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1162, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/app/jython/2.5.2/Lib/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 925, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
socket.sslerror: (-1, 'SSL exception')
```

I'm not too familiar with SSL and am not familiar with what the -1 error code means.  I was under the assumption that httplib2 doesn't verify the SSL cert.

A regular wget fails, but a wget --no-check-cert works.

```
$ wget -qO- https://www.example.com --no-check-certificate

Up
```

Accessing the URL through a browser also seems to work fine.  Am I doing something wrong in the code?  Or does a the socket.sslerror: (-1, 'SSL exception') mean something else is wrong?

Comment: Is this your own URL?  Try accessing a public URL like https : //www.google.com.  I've seen SSL suites with certificate checking disabled still complain if the certificate is self-signed or malformed.

Comment: @Pace Yes, this is our own URL. I can't test a public URL since this server is in the green zone without direct access to the internet. I tried a few other HTTPS URLs within our network and get the same exception. All use 3rd party signed certs, not self-signed. How do I check if a cert is malformed?

Comment: The only other thing I could think of that would make it malformed was if the name on the certificate didn't match the hostname of the server.  If you get the same error on other servers that are working fine then that likely isn't the issue.

Comment: What version of httplib2 are you using?

Comment: And what implementation of Python?

Answer (score 1):

SSL support depends on your underlying socket module.  In this case it appears you do have ssl support.  You can disable it with...

```
http = httplib2.Http(cache=None, timeout=30, disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
```

Comment: This didn't work. The same exception is seen, but this was outputed before the exception was thrown which shows SSL was disabled. Jul 17, 2012 10:32:15 PM com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager INFO: ssl.disable.url.hostname.verification.CWPKI0027I

Comment: Interesting.  That message comes from WebSphere and indicates that it will not be checking to make sure the hostname matches the certificate but it doesn't necessarily indicate that it has disabled the check to see if the certificate is trusted :(